# Always the input parameter is NULL in wcf rest C#

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I have the service "ImportStream" wcf post :

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
void ImportStream(StreamObject data);
```

And the class StreamObject :

```
[DataContract]
public class StreamObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public Char Comma { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Stream Stream { get; set; }
}
```

My code:

```
public void ImportStream(StreamObject data)
{
    // ....
}
```

I test it with POSTMAN:

```
{
    "Comma": ",",
    "Stream": "test;;;;test2,result....!!!!"
}
```

but always I have data is NULL !! I don't understand what it is the probem?
How can I fix it?

Comment: Probably because you give it a string named Stream, instead of an actual stream. It can't convert a string to a stream.

Comment: any reasons for using `Stream` with JSON serializer? it doesn't make sens

Comment: In fact,I want enter  a Stream , but before it I have to enter a comma ',' 
That is my objectif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how to use the `Stream` in the Json serialization

First problem that I see is that `Stream` is an abstract class. How it can be deserialized ?

Another problem is that not all streams can be serialized:

```
var value = new StreamObject { Comma = ',' };
value.Stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("turn left then right and go straight"));

var str = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(value);
```

raises error like `Timeouts are not supported on this stream.` when trying to serialise the MemoryStream.

Please consider using the `byte[]` or `string` data type but not `Stream`.

You can use it with `string` according to the Postman sample you had shown:

```
[DataContract]
public class StreamObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public Char Comma { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Stream { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , Ok I understand the problem, and I change my data Type to string , my input object in POSTMAN :
{
"Comma" :",",
"Stream": "test;;;;test2,result....!!!!"
}
but Unfortunately always when I test it ,I  get data  NULL !

Comment: @IngTun2018 I can serialize and deserialize `StreamObject` with `string Stream` property without any problem. Seems that your case is not about serialization now. Probably you have to check the [WCF Rest sample](http://www.wcftutorial.net/How_to_create_RESTful_Service.aspx). ASP.NET controllers require `[FromBody]` parameter attribute for example. Do you use POST method in the Postman btw ?

Comment: It is ok , I modify BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest
to BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare .it works now.
Thank you for your help